# i want to conver some my custom function for classic asp to a dll file by vb 6

Tags: asp-classic, vb6

this is my classic asp function :

```
Private Function XMLHttpRequest(XmlHttpMode, XmlHttpURL, XmlHttpData)

    Dim MyXmlhttp
    Set MyXmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")                  '
    With MyXmlhttp
        .setTimeouts 6000000, 600000, 600000, 600000                              '

            .Open "GET", XmlHttpURL, True
            .Option(4) = 13056 '
            .Option(6) = True '         

            .SetRequestHeader "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"        

        .send (XmlHttpData)
        .waitForResponse (2000)             

      If MyXmlhttp.Status = 200 Then           
             XMLHttpRequest = .ResponseBody           
        Else
           XMLHttpRequest = "error code:" & .Status            
        End If            

    End With

    Set MyXmlhttp = Nothing
End Function
```

in iis run very good,but i convert to dll by vb6 ,then give me a error tip:

[image]

> “Object does not support this property or method“

VB6 source code Reference libary below，i want to know what object  wo i need include my vb code project (for make dll file,then i can call in my classi asp source code).thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Microsoft WinHTTP Services** as your screenshot shows, declare your variable as WinHttpRequest instead of XMLHttpRequest. Everything should work the same as with the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: this is reason for my classic asp codes run error ?i don't know rename my variable,then what happend occured.